# Proof Key for Code Exchange Error in Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: django

AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.

I have followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msid-django-web-app-sign-in/1-introduction and got Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.